# How to float left only if another element exists

Tags: css, css-float

First of all, please be patient, because I don't speak english very well and I don't know if I will manage to explain the solution very well. So...

I have this HTML

```
<div id='container'>

    <div class='picture'>
        <img src='...'>
    </div>

    <div class='description'>
        <div id='attrb1' class='clearfix'>...</div>
        <div id='attrb2' class='clearfix'>...</div>
        <div id='attrb3' class='clearfix'>...</div>
        <div id='attrb4' class='clearfix'>...</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The clearfix class is implemented as explained [here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

I want the .picture div to stay on the left and the .description div to stay on the right. So I wrote this CSS

```
.picture { float: left; width: 100px; }
.picture img { width: 100px; height: auto; }
.description { float: right; width: 815px; }
```

Till now, everything is ok.

But sometimes, **no picture is present**. In this case I want that .description div extends for all the .container div width. So I tried to remove the width of both divs:

```
.picture { float: left; }
.picture img { width: 100px; height: auto; }
.description { float: right; }
```

But the .description div flows below the .picture div (if the picture is present)

Here is a screenshot:
[image: two .container divs: the first with .picture div and the second without]

Comment: can you add screen-shot examples of the behavior?  What do you mean by 'any picture is present'?

Comment: Seems to work fine here:  http://jsfiddle.net/mWk7v/

Comment: Hi N1tr0, thank you for your effort. I've edited the question and added an image. All I want is that in the second .container div, the .description div cover all the width. It's the first time I use jsfiddle. I've edited your code, can you see it?

Comment: Hi Marco, not sure what's going on with it but I get a gateway timeout now for the jsfiddle example.  I think you broke it.  Way to go. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UQngw/

When I disable css

```
.clearfix {
    #display: inline-block;
}
```

Look like `display: line-block;` let the div as width as it can.

**UPDATE**
Well, I just find that my code have some problem when the text so long...
http://jsfiddle.net/HbCaK/3/
I have disabled the following css in this try, but I am not sure if this is suitable in your case:

```
.description {
    #float: right;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    #display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    #display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use min-width for .picture instead:

```
.picture { float: left; min-width: 100px; }
.picture img { width: auto height: auto; }
.description { float: right; width: 815px; }
```

When the img tag is removed from the picture div the layout should collapse like what I think you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunally, the only effect of this modification is that the .description div stays below the .picture div. When the .picture div is not present, the .description div should be large 930px

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float: right;` from the .picture class.  It will automatically line up next to the other one because of the float left.

I've created a new jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/mu2MV/

This also adds vertical scrolling if the content gets too large.  Otherwise it breaks out and wraps under the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will solve your problems....

```
.picture img { width: 100px; height: auto; }
#container > div:nth-of-type(1){
    float: left;    
}
#container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    float: right;     
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vYwYe/5/

http://jsfiddle.net/vYwYe/6/

Comment: Kindly reminder, look like Marco Panichi hope the .description always beside the picture